# angularjs on asp.net error failed to load resources on single page app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

Good Day;

i am new to angular and mostly do my work on asp.net this morning i tried playing with the SPA using angular now i am testing a sample app which when the linked the actual page will be loaded to a div with ng-view directive now the controller has two function one is to show a value for the text input after the page loaded and the other is wired to a button clicked here is the code:

```
app.controller("PersonalController", function ($scope, $location) {
    get();
    function get ()
    {
        $scope.Email = "angelogasa1022@gmail.com";
    }

    $scope.save = function () {
        $scope.Email = "eloelo22@gmail.com";

    };
});
```

the page is showing and the email value is correct but when i tried to click the button nothing happens i look at the chrome developer tools and an error pops up 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

is there any settings to avoid this error?

thank you

Comment: Are you able to post the html ?

Comment: yes actually the page is posted

Comment: Can you please include the html here?